# Prevent DROP COLUMN in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, ddl

Can I stop DROP COLUMN from succeeding on particular tables in PostgreSQL 9 or 10 or later?

My application makes some assumptions about columns being forever, not disappearing. I'm afraid of later programmers forgetting about this constraint.

I know triggers can fire to control INSERT, MODIFY, and DELETE of rows. But what about [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language)? Can I protect against certain changes to the table structure?

Security might be one way, assigning permissions to users and roles. But these future programmers will be allowed to *add* columns, only *dropping* columns is forbidden.

I am *not* concerned about malicious activity. I'm defending against the eager-beavers who may move too fast to remember the bigger picture.

Comment: If you are afraid that programmer will forget that certain columns are important, make sure you have proper integration tests. And if they can drop random columns without knowing what they are doing then they **will** find a way to work around whatever "protection" you come up with

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Fair point. Certainly I will have meta-data stored that can will be used to verify table integrity. Nevertheless, if I can stop the errant programmer at the source, that would be nice. I am not concerned about malicious activity, I'm just defending against the clever eager-beavers who may move too fast to remember the bigger picture.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Event Triggers

There are [event triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/event-triggers.html) to control DDLs, trapping for the event `sql_drop`.

Call [`CREATE EVENT TRIGGER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/sql-createeventtrigger.html). In the trigger function, check to see if the object being dropped is one of your important columns. If so, raise exception to roll-back transaction.

> The `sql_drop` event occurs just before the `ddl_command_end` event trigger for any operation that drops database objects. To list the objects that have been dropped, use the set-returning function `pg_event_trigger_dropped_objects()` from the `sql_drop` event trigger code (see [Section 9.28](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-event-triggers.html)). Note that the trigger is executed after the objects have been deleted from the system catalogs, so it's not possible to look them up anymore.

Example:

```
drop table if exists t;
drop event trigger if exists etg;
drop function if exists fetg();

create function fetg() returns event_trigger language plpgsql as $$
begin
  if exists (
    select 1
    from pg_event_trigger_dropped_objects() as t
    where
      t.object_type = 'table column' and
      t.object_identity like any(array['%.t.y', 'public.tt.zz']))
  then
    raise exception 'Columns t.y and public.tt.zz are important!';
  end if;
end $$;

create event trigger etg on sql_drop execute procedure fetg();

create table t(x int, y int);
alter table t drop column y;
```

More docs:
[Events](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/event-trigger-definition.html)
[Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-event-triggers.html)

Comment: Went above and over in this one.  =) Awesome answer.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Everything is simple if you know where to dig :o)

Comment: Available from PostgreSQL 9.4.